# Does Windows Phone support app widgets?

Tags: apps

Does Windows Phone support app widgets like Android phones do?

Comment: What's an "app widget" - it might be useful to include context of the functionality you're wanting to see on your Windows Phone?

Answer (score 3):

No and there's no need.

One of the key features of the Windows Phone platform are Live Tiles, which provide a snapshot of information on your Start Screen. We have Live Tiles that will deliver weather information, appointments, TV shows, and even gaming progress.

Personally, I like how I can glance at the weather and appointment Tiles to see what the current temperature is or how long I have until the next meeting.  Other than that, I generally use the Live Tiles as a shortcut to the many apps I have pinned to my Start Screen.

I cannot think why would anyone want widgets when we have live tiles